# Is there a convenient way to port a .apk file to a .swf file?

Tags: porting

My friend just made a game and has a bunch of installs on the Android/Google Play.

I'm curious if it's possible at all to port said game to a flash game.  I've seen tutorials on how to port an .swf to an .apk, but I haven't seen anything yet that would make it seem to go backwards.

I'd love to help my friend get extra exposure for his game.  Is there any way he can port it?

Comment: While unlikely, it is possible that the .apk file(just a zip file) contains the .swf inside it.
For ios, adobe converts the swf to the ios exe file format, it is possible that for android it just stores the .swf as a resource inside the .apk.

Comment: The exact procedure depends on how exactly your friend made the game, so maybe you should tell us that. In most cases the answer is "you can't", because the two are fundamentally different technologies (.apk is an Android app, .swf is a Flash movie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convenient? Unlikely. It may seem like just a file conversion, but it's much more than that. An apk file is an application package designed to run on the Android operating system. An swf file is an animation or applet designed to run in a flash player. They're completely different technologies. Similar to asking if there's a way to convert an .exe to a .swf. One of them is meant to run on an operating system, the other is run in much higher level application.

You might think since there are tools to turn swf files into apks that the reverse should be just as simple. It's not. "Converting" a swf into an apk is more like taking a pre-made Android application designed for playing flash content and adding the resources found in a swf file.

This type of conversion will have to be done at the source code level, not the packaged file level. It likely means re-writing the source code into a language capable of exporting to swf (likely actionscript).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Adobe Flash Cs4 or latest applications. Use AS3 codes and publish it to Android apk. Or you want to try http://apkgen.com/ to publish into apk. If you find it easy Good luck. If you want to hack your .swf into other apk extensions It will not allow you to do that. You have to be owner of your .swf and prevent legal actions to do so. or you can use eclipse to use your own .swf games to android .apk.

Comment: This is the opposite of what the question asks for.